# Does using multiple speakers degrade quality?

Tags: audio, music

I have an amp and 4 speakers. I want to "daisy chain" the speakers together like so:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out if doing series and/or parallel connections in the diagram above will degrade the sound quality/volume/anything else when compared to a single speaker. It's a pretty simple question, but I haven't managed to find any similar questions out there (maybe I'm using the wrong terminology?)

I understand the concepts of Ohm's law and all how to balance the impedance. This question is not asking about that.

Comment: Should I repost there? Or is there a way to move the post from superuser -> EE.SE?

Comment: Flag your question "other" and ask a moderator to move it ...

Comment: If the amplifier is solid-state it generally doesn't matter. If it's 'vacuum state' you may have impedance matching problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fine in most cases...

If the lengths of your wires are short and gauge (thickness) of the wires is large then your configuration will have no noticeable impact on the audio aside from the impedance issue -- which will only reduce power/volume if you design correctly and corrupt the audio if you don't.

### But those other cases... ;)

You can run into trouble with phasing at long distances. Since the length between amplifier and speaker A is L1 and amplifier and speaker B is L1 + L2 it is impossible for both speakers to be playing exactly the same sound at exactly the same time. This difference in output is called a *phase shift* which is a mathematical term expressing the difference in angle between two equi-periodic signals represented in a polar plane (in case you care ;).

It takes sound about 3 milliseconds to travel 1 meter in air while the audio signal can travel through 450,000m (450km) of cable in the same timeframe. When your distances get to 100's of meters phase shift can become critically important. It depends on your configuration and how sensitive your application is to distortion.